# Interpolate variable into class with Angular

Tags: css, angular, string-interpolation

I would like to dynamically generate a class name for my element. For example,
``` <span class=``icon icon-${route.title}``></span> ``` (had to use double backticks here, but it should really be just one set of backticks.)

```js
    <ul class="sidebar-list">
      <li *ngFor="let route of menuRoutes.items">
        <span class=`icon icon-${route.title}`></span>
        <a routerLink="/{{route.path}}" routerLinkActive="active">{{ 'menu.' + route.title | translate}}</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span class="icon icon-{{route.title}}"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also archive this by using a **[ngClass]** directive

```
<span [ngClass]="['icon', route.title]"></span>
```